# Достать последнюю модель по дате создания Django

Tags: python, django, model

Подскажите как сделать запрос через Model.objects.get() либо через Model.objects.filter(), чтобы получить последнюю созданную модель. Есть поле

```
create_date = models.DateField(
    'Создан',
    auto_now_add=True
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В модели в мете можно определить полe [get_latest_by](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/models/options.html#django.db.models.Options.get_latest_by):

```
get_latest_by = "create_date"
```

Тогда запрос

```
Model.objects.latest()
```

выдаст вам последнюю модель, отсортированную по полю `create_date`, а запрос

```
Model.objects.earliest()
```

выдаст первую созданную модель.

Comment: спасибо это то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
model = Model.objects.all().order_by("create_date").last()
```

ПС: не проверял.
переводится как выбрать все модели, отсортировать по дате создания и взять оттуда последнюю модель.

Comment: а вы этот метод в доках нашли?

Answer (score 1):

Последний созданный объект

```
Model.objects.latest('create_date')
```

Comment: Мне кажеться в таком случае запрос вернет кучу обьектов, а это может занять память.

Comment: Проверил, вернул одну последнюю запись. Без нулевого индекса, будет все отсортировано по дате в обратном порядке.

Comment: вопрос в том, сколько обьектов возвращаеться из базы. Есть подозрение что много, а потом силами Джанго выбираеться один.

Comment: выбирается один не силами джанги, но джанго возвращает все.

Comment: изменил свой комментарий, ознакомьтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте слайс, джанго его понимает правильно

```
Model.objects.all().order_by('-create_date')[:1]
```

Comment: тоесть в этом случае сохраняеться ленивость запроса и Джанго из базы получит один обьект? Или много а потом сделает слайс?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Используется лимит, запрашивает только один